# Why do we need Anaconda 2.7?

Tags: python, anaconda

Since we can [install the Python 3.6 version Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) and create a Python 2 environment as below:

```
conda create -n py2 python=2
```

Why do we ever need to install the Python 2.7 version Anaconda? Thanks

Comment: Some people prefer Python 2.7, and Anaconda 2.7 is a one-step route to installing it. If you download Anaconda 3.6 and then switch to Python 2.7, you're doubling the bandwidth you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do we ever need to install the Python 2.7 version Anaconda?

There is an enormous amount of legacy code (and code currently being written in 2.7).  Also, a number of important Python third-party libraries are still 2.7 only. You would need Anaconda 2.7 to run all that code.

People may not be able to use 3.6 if they need to interoperate with [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) (2.7 only), [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) (2.7 or 3.3), [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) (2.7 only), or [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/) (2.7 or 3.6).

If you have no such dependencies, then it is best to install 3.6 and work only with the newer Python.

Answer (score 2):

Direct from the developer:

> Which version should I download and install? With Anaconda you can run multiple versions of Python in isolated environments, so choose the download with the Python version that you use more often, as that will be your default Python version.

The version you install will be the default python for your system with the whole anaconda packages. If you mainly work with python 2, installing anaconda 2 is still more convenient than creating an additional python 2 environment.

In the end it's about ease of use and freedom of choice, if nothing else.